# DNS resolution with different (arbitrary) DNS server

Tags: c#, dns

Is it possible in c# to provide the DNS server address to resolve the IP from a non-default DNS server.
example: my DNS is: ns.isp.com
I want to resolve IP of www.test.com using ns.other.com
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Net.Dns` does not support these kinds of queries. You should implement the DNS protocol into your application and there is a [good example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23673/DNS-NET-Resolver-C) on codeproject.

Answer (score 5):

If you do opt to use a DNS library such as

http://www.simpledns.com/dns-client-lib.aspx

It's worth noting that there's no guarantees how much time the DNS server takes to respond, if it responds successfully at all. The library has a timeout, but it's fairly long, 30 seconds I believe.

As a result, DNS lookups usually should be written in asynchronous, threaded code, so the DNS lookup won't block the entire process.

Also, you usually don't want to ever do DNS lookups in web server code, because a slowly responding DNS server can take up all your web server resources.

Answer (score 1):

DNS Client Library for .NET

http://www.simpledns.com/dns-client-lib.aspx

At the top of the feature list it says:

Features

- Lookup any DNS record type (A, AAAA, MX, SPF, SOA, SRV, etc.).
- Optionally specify which DNS servers to query (default = DNS servers
  from local system config).

A C# sample (from the site):

```
Lookup IPv4 addresses for www.simpledns.com using specific DNS servers: VB.NET  C#
var Options = new JHSoftware.DnsClient.RequestOptions();
Options.DnsServers = new System.Net.IPAddress[] { 
           System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("1.1.1.1"), 
           System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("2.2.2.2") };
var IPs = JHSoftware.DnsClient.LookupHost("www.simpledns.com", 
                                          JHSoftware.DnsClient.IPVersion.IPv4, 
                                          Options);
foreach(var IP in IPs)
{
   Console.WriteLine(IP.ToString());
}
```